# Open Relay for internal IPs

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, smtp, windows-sbs

How do I enable SBS 2008 and exchange to send mail via SMTP without authentication?

I have a handful of network scanners that don't have anyway of configuring SMTP authentication. So I want the SBS/Exchange to be an open relay (either for just the scanners or for the company internal mail) so that the scans can be emailed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an article related to setting this up in Exchange Server 2007.

http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/12/28/432013.aspx

Comment: +1, Wow, I'm glad someone's around to call me out on my brainfarts.